# Why doesn't redirect cause infinite loop?

Tags: ruby, sinatra

```
.
├── public
│   └── imgs
│       └── alien1.png
└── routes.rb



#routes.rb
require 'sinatra'

get "/imgs/*.*" do
  puts "****"
  redirect to('/imgs/alien1.png')
end
```

When I enter the following url in my browser:

```
http://localhost:4567/imgs/blah.jpg
```

that matches the only route in routes.rb, so the redirect executes, and alien1.png is displayed in my browser.  But why doesn't the redirect match the route again?

If I do this:

```
require 'sinatra'

get "/dog" do
  'woof woof'
end

get "/imgs/*.*" do
  puts "***"
  redirect to("/dog")
end
```

...the redirect hits the /dog route and its block executes displaying 'woof woof' in my browser.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sinatra has a configuration enabled by default to serve static files without going through routes if the file exists. From the documentation:

> :static - enable/disable static file routes
>
> Boolean that determines whether static files should be served from the application’s public directory (see the :public_folder setting). When :static is truthy, Sinatra will check if a static file exists and serve it before checking for a matching route.
>
> The :static setting is enabled by default when the public directory exists.

If you have your public folder configured to be the images folder, then that's the reason why it does not enter the redirection loop.

Comment: *Sinatra will check if a static file exists and serve it before checking for a matching route.*  I had it backwards.  Thanks!

Comment: To make Sinatra not look for files in /public before trying to match routes, add `disable :static` to the top of your file--in my case that WILL cause the redirect to match the route again, causing my browser to issue an error saying there were too many redirects.